# Autofill Text Field Value with Current Page URL

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, textfield

All I am looking to do is autofill a *hidden* text field with the current page URL, so that when the user submits the form, I know the page they sent the form from. This will save me a ton of headaches dealing with inquiries.

In other words, when the page loads, I'd need the text field **value** to be **value="http://www.example.com/"**

Ideally, looking to accomplish this with just Javascript/HTML.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you can give your hidden field an ID, put the following in your `onload` or document-ready processing:

```
document.getElementById("yourHiddenFieldId").value = window.location.href;
```

Comment: Awesome! Works perfect. Knew it would be simple. Thank you very much for the help. This will come in handy for other tricks too now that I understand it.